# How can I use macro to define different datatypes depending on parameter？

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```cpp
#define MYPTR(n) （（n）==16？（USHORT*）：（BYTE*））
```

What I want to do is, if n==16 then `MYPTR(n) pData;` should equal to `USHORT* pData`. Otherwise it should be `BYTE* pData`

But it did not work. I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: `#if`, `#elif`, `#else`, `#endif`.

Comment: Why do you want to use a macro for this? If you're using C++, there's probably a better way to achieve what you want with templates. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with templates, in a way that is more type-safe and powerful than the macro would be.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

template<int N>
using myptr = std::conditional_t<N == 16, uint16_t*, uint8_t*>;

static_assert( std::is_same<myptr<16>, uint16_t*>::value );
static_assert( std::is_same<myptr<8>, uint8_t*>::value );
```